# Awk shell scripting using gsub to remove whitespace

Tags: shell, awk, gsub

I have a shell script that I would like to export out the 'data' variable without any whitespace in it. I have tried gsub() but I cannot seem to get it work.

```
export data="`grep -e 'P/N  :' "$xfile" | awk '{print substr($3,3)}' `"
if [ "$data" = "" ] && [ "$skipdata" = "0" ]
then
  export data="`grep -e 'P/N:' "$xfile" | awk '{print substr($2,3)}' |
    awk '{ if (index($1,"-D") != 0)
            $1 = (substr($1, 1, (index($1,"-D") -1))) "-DIE" }
            { print $1 }' `"

  if [ "$data" = "" ]
  then
    export data="`grep -e 'CUST PART NO:' "$xfile" | awk '{print substr($4,3)}' |
    awk '{ if (index($1,"-D") != 0)
            $1 = (substr($1, 1, (index($1,"-D") -1))) "-DIE" }
            { print $1 }' `"
  fi
fi
```

Ultimately I would like $data to be whitespace free. Can I do like:

```
export data="awk '{gsub($data," ","");print}"
```

Comment: when I am not sure about a function call syntax, arguments etc, I would do a `man (g)awk` and search for that function. Have you tried that? you will find the answer there.

Comment: Your script has enough issues that it would not be worth using it as a starting point and trying to correct it. Just post some sample input and expected output so we can show you how to write it from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It LOOKS like your script should be written as just something like:

```
data=$(awk -F':' '
$1 ~ /^(P\/N[[:space:]]*|CUST PART NO)$/ {
    sub(/-D.*/,"-DIE",$2)
    gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",$2)
    print $2
}
' "$xfile")
```

We can use that as a starting point and if it doesn't do exactly what you want then update your question to include some sample lines from $xfile and your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntax is

```
gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/,"")
```

so you could probably use

```
data=$(awk '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/,""); print}' <<< "$data")
```